# Why were hundreds of Italians driving from Szeged, Hungary into Romania at around 3pm on 30th July 2016?

Tags: driving, borders, routes, romania, italian-citizens

This question may seem stupid or irrelevant but I'm very curious.

Last week I was traveling to Romania through Hungary, I was crossing border between Szeged (HU) and Arad (RO). Standing in the line to passports control, I was literally surrounded by Italian cars (license plates). After that, I travelled through Romania for next 8 days and I met almost no Italians neither in the mountains nor in Constanta area, so where they were all driving to? To Bulgaria? Some particular place in Romania that Italians visit?

Comment: What date, day, time of day? If they were all travelling at once, and there wasn't a scattering of Italians outside of this cluster, most likely they knew each other and were travelling en mass to a private event e.g. a wedding or similar. If there was a scattering of seemingly unrelated Italians it could be a special interest public event, perhaps in Timișoara, but you'll need to specify date and time. It's not necessarily Italian-specific, they might be mostly Romanians living long-term in Italy coming back for this event.

Comment: it was July 30th at about 3pm, I don't think they were all driving together cause I'm talking about dozens/hundreds of cars, I was stuck in line for nearly an hour, cars passing by on each lane and 95% were Italian

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the title with the extra info. I love how specific this question is... it's got me really curious now too!

Comment: Did they have footie support bumper stickers?

Comment: Or they're big fans of Iron Maiden who gave a concert in Bucharest on the 30th, part of the Rock The City festival.

Comment: Iron Maiden fans would look kind of specific which would have probably caught my attention, these people were pretty ordinary looking, maybe families, just as if they were going to seaside, however, like I wrote in the thread, there were too many of them and later on I saw nearly no one with Italian plates

Comment: @Dorothy Iron Maiden are on a world tour though and had just played three dates in Italy

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travel.